# MySQL is running but Laravel 5 can't connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 app running that uses MySQL.

My app returns an error:

```
live.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)' in /var/www/app/admin/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:55
```

I researched but no solution did help.

- My MySQL server is running
- I can use the username and password used in Laravel to access de DB via
  phpMyAdmin On the same server I have some Wordpress pages (using
  MySQL) running without problems
- The file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  exists, I ran chmod 777 to make sure enough rights are granted.

I don't think that this is a duplicate since my MySQL server is running and to me this seems to be a Laravel issue as described in my question.

Comment: You have the .env edited?

Comment: edit this
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
in .env file and restart your project